# Implementation of BeginUpdate and EndUpdate

Tags: c#

1) I'm working on a project and I saw this piece of code, I don't understand what is the point of the Monitor.Lock statement. Can someone explain what its trying to do?

2) the postscript underscroll in the parameter name is really annoying, anyone else seen this naming convention?

```
public class FieldsChangeableHelper<T> : IFieldsChangeable<T>
{
    object _lock;
    int _lockCount;
    FieldChanges<T> _changes;

    public FieldsChangeableHelper()
    {
        _lock = new object();
        _lockCount = 0;
    }

    public void AddChange(T field_, object oldValue_)
    {
        if (_changes == null)
            _changes = new FieldChanges<T>(field_, oldValue_);
        else
            _changes.AddChange(field_, oldValue_);
        if (RaiseEvent(_changes))
            _changes = null;
    }

    #region IFieldsChangeable Members

    public void BeginUpdate()
    {
        if (System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref _lockCount) == 1)
            Monitor.Enter(_lock);
    }

    public void EndUpdate()
    {
        if (System.Threading.Interlocked.Decrement(ref _lockCount) == 0)
        {
            FieldChanges<T> changes = _changes;
            _changes = null;
            Monitor.Exit(_lock);
            RaiseEvent(changes);
        }
    }


    protected bool RaiseEvent(FieldChanges<T> changes_)
    {
        if (_lockCount == 0 && Changed != null && changes_ != null)
        {
            Changed(this, changes_);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public event FieldsChanged<T> Changed;

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Monitor.Lock locks the portion of code when multiple thread tries to execute the same piece in parallel. It is made to ensure that only 1 guy is altering/executing the context. Look at the MSDN.

Although its best practice that the locking object is always static, but in your case it is not. Which might pose some problem if your instantiating multiple objects on an open type.

Note one thing, in generics static on open T is different for different type, i.e static member in an Open Type class in your case is different for T i.e DateTime, string, etc.

In csharp, private members of a type are usually named with prefixed _

Answer (score 0):

The way i read it: BeginUpdate() ensures that the current thread calling has exclusive access to the instance and that change events practically will be batched and raised once EndUpdate is called. The author wanted to deal with recursion by itself (e.g. calling BeginUpdate() on the same thread multiple times) and a mechanism to batch UpdateEvents untill after the lock has been released. Because, there is a potential deadlock when raising Events when you still have a lock on yourself. event subscribers might want to access your members and therefore have to lock the sender instance which is already locked.

The whole conditional locking is not required (if my analyses is correct ofcourse) since locks based on the Monitor class are recursive and counted.

There is another problem with the locking mechanism, that is: currently when one thread holds a lock. The second thread wont even wait for the lock but will simply continue without a lock since the lock is conditional! this seems like a big bug!

Regarding the naming convention. I use it myself for a way of differentiating privates from parameters and locals. Its a preference which many C# coding conventions recommend. This helps in a case like this:

```
void Method(int number)
{
    // no need to refer to this since:
    //this.number = number; 
    // can be replaced with
    _number = number;
}
```

Comment: But only the first thread will call Monitor.Lock since its behind a
System.Threading.Interlocked increment?

Comment: @Ant - Right, i updated my answer. This is a bug and a good reason not to do to much manually when it comes to synchronization unless you really know what youre doing